# Unable to install Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows-7

I have a clean install of Windows 7.

I downloaded Microsoft Security Essentials from the Microsoft website, and attempted to install it, but at the end of the installation wizard I get the following message:

"Can't complete the Microsoft Security Essentials Installation Wizard". "An error has prevented the Microsoft Security Essentials Installation Wizard from continuing.

Comment: Does it show up as installed in the control panel?

Comment: Have you tried downloading it again and reinstall it? Might be a corrupt install file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just reinstalled Windows 7 and then tried to reinstall Microsoft Security Essentials and then it worked. There must have been something wrong with my Windows install. Thanks anyway guys.